# Dynamic Form Using Bootstrap's Modal and save to database

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create dynamic form using bootstrap's modal as form inputs and save to database.

first, i have index page :

[+ Add Data]

[Submit Data]

when I click button above, it shows modal that contain input fields, and when I click "submit on modal" it will store data to index page as temporary data before I click "Submit Data" on Index Page, example:

[+ Add Data]

[Data 1st] <- this is data I've been added

[Data 2nd] <- this is data I've been added

[Submit Data] <- this is button to save to the database.

so what should i do first in this scheme?

Comment: That is quite unclear without code and HTML markup.

Comment: Hello, please add to your post what you currently have so far and what's the problem. Right now you are currently asking an answer from the bottom up

Comment: I think this can be easily achieved, your main form should be in the index page with the submit button, the modal is a placeholder for inputs. All you have to do is when you open the modal and input something, use jquery to add the value to the actual form and everything else is just normal